# Как правильно хранить экземпляры класса?

Tags: c#

Как правильно хранить экземпляры класса ?

Так ?

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Код
    }
}

class Rabotnik
{

    public string familiya;
    public string imya;
    public string otchestvo;

}

class Rabotniki
{
    public List<Rabotnik> spisokRabotnikov = new List<Rabotnik>();
}
```

Или где то вне отдельного класса ?

```
class Program
{

    public List<Rabotnik> spisokRabotnikov = new List<Rabotnik>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Код
    }
}

class Rabotnik
{

    public string familiya;
    public string imya;
    public string otchestvo;

}
```

Comment: Что значит `вне отдельного класса`?

Comment: @tym32167 например в class Program

Comment: Все зависит от структуры проекта. Храните там, где вам удобно, хоть в IoC контейнер засовывайте. Просто первый вариант, хорош тем, что у вас есть один ответственный класс, на который вы потом можете ссылаться там, где это нужно, он один и отвечает за одну основную логику - работники, там могут быть методы например поиска, добавления, удаления, назначить зарплату группе работников и куча всего другого, что относится именно к "работникам", это логичное и удобное поведение, а что будет если этот список находится например в окне? Логично будет обращаться к окну, чтобы добавить работника?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ очень доходчиво, спасибо! Делал всегда для списка отдельный класс, хоть и нет там никакой дальнейшей логики, а ща стало казаться что тупо выглядит отдельный класс, вот и решил поинтересоваться. В итоге всё логично - спасибо!

Comment: Это, кстати, одно из правил SOLID, а именно SRP - Единственная ответственность. Так что советую вам разобрать эти правила. Допустим ваш второй пример нарушает его, ибо класс программы вдруг становится ответственным за работников, почему? зачем? Старайтесь каждый класс делать ответственным только за одну определенную задачу, а внутри методы, которые также должны отвечать только за что-то одно. Если у вас в классе "РАБОТНИК" вдруг идет поиск других работников, или допустим вывод на экран какой-то информации, то это нарушение, ибо не его ответственность.

Comment: Но опять же, это все набор принятых рекомендаций, которым многие следуют, ибо они очень сильно упрощают жизнь. Если у вас проект всего из 1-го класса, то зачем вам лепить отдельный класс для списка? Тут все индивидуально и надо понимать, когда эти правила стоит применять. Вот поэтому, у вас `а ща стало казаться что тупо выглядит отдельный класс`. Но когда ваш проект разрастется в нечто большое, состоящие их десятка классов, то вы заметите кашу, ибо у вас все в одном месте, смешено друг с другом, что не есть хорошо.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ доходчиво, спасибо!

Comment: Добавлю вот ещё что. В разных местах нужны разные типы коллекций. Например, для привязки к GUI - BindingList или ObservableCollection. Для работы в многопотоке - конкурретные коллекции (или иммутабельные). Для быстрого поиска лучше взять HashSet или Dictionary. И создавать для каждого случай класс-обёртку - слишком расточительно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего нет смысла создавать класс для простого хранения одного списка. Только если в этом классе планируется ещё какая-то логика, как написал @EvgeniyZ.
Для хранения работников должно всё же использоваться какое-то хранилище (например БД). Тогда для этих самых работников должны быть созданы специальные классы, отвечающие за извлечение работников из хранилища с разной фильтрацией (RabotnikExtractor) и за добавление нового работника (RabotnikStorer). Тогда не нужно держать некий глобальный список работников (его ещё как то нужно поддерживать в актуальном состоянии, ведь в многопользовательском случае его кто-то может поменять), а можно спокойно получить актуальный список там где это действительно нужно.